# Guessing Game errors (mostly scanner)

Tags: java, runtime-error

*edit 1* - I changed all sc.nextInt to Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) and I now have some errors but less

*edit 2* - It now runs but I am something getting things printed 2x, the game does not end at the end of round 10 and I'm missing a total wins line at the end. I think the error occurs after a win.

*edit 3* - 2x cold/hot printing fixed. fixed the 2x header (repeat line left in wins method). New (and hopefully last error) - first round the game only allows 3 tries, other rounds 4. sample run:

```
I will choose a number between 1 and 10
You have 3 tries to get it right

Round 1

Enter a new guess: 5
Cold
5
Cold
5
You lose!
You have won 0 out of 1 rounds.

Round 2

Enter a new guess: 5
Cold
5
Cold
5
Cold
5
You lose!
You have won 0 out of 2 rounds.

Round 3

Enter a new guess: 5
Cold
5
Cold
5
Cold
5
You lose!
You have won 0 out of 3 rounds.
```

class 1:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessRunner 
{   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("I will choose a number between 1 and 10" + 
                    '\n' + "You have 3 tries to get it right" + '\n');

    GuessCalc game = new GuessCalc();
    while (game.getRounds() <= 10)
    {   
        System.out.println('\n' + "Round " + game.getRounds() + '\n');
        System.out.print("Enter a new guess: ");
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        do
        {
            game.rounds(guess);
            guess = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        } 
        while (game.roundOver == false);

        System.out.println(game.wins());
    }

    sc.close();
}
}
```

class 2:

```
public class GuessCalc 
{
private int wins;
private int rounds = 1;
private int num = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
private int tries = 0;
public boolean roundOver;

/**
 * Runs the rounds and determines if they win
 * @return outcome the boolean true if they won or false if they lost
 */
public String rounds(int guess)
{       
    if (guess == num)   //player won
    {
        wins++;
        rounds++;
        tries = 0;
        System.out.println("You win!");
        num = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);   //new number
        roundOver = true;
    }

    else if (tries == 3)    //out of tries
    {
        rounds++;
        tries = 0;
        System.out.println("You lose!");
        num = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);   //new number
        roundOver = true;
    }

    else
    {  
        hotOrCold(guess);
        roundOver = false;   
    }
}

/**
 * Tells the player if they are hot or cold
 */
public void hotOrCold(int guess)
{
    if (guess == num - 1 || guess == num + 1)    //if they are off by 1
        System.out.println("Hot");
    else         // if they are further than 1 away
        System.out.println("Cold");

   tries++;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of wins and makes a new header
 * @return the String with the number of wins and new header
 */
public String wins()
    {return("You have won " + wins + " out of " + (rounds - 1) + " rounds.");}

/**
 * Returns the number of rounds played
 * @return rounds the number of rounds
 */
public int getRounds()
    {return rounds;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with Scanner is that Scanner is very, very strange. I've been using it for years and she hates that I use her for only fast and dirty input. I don't even want to begin to describe the bizarre things that happen, but the explanation is usually around how non-nextLine() methods deal with newline characters (whether they consume/ignore them or not)

My advice with scanner is to only ever use its hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods. They are the only methods I found were every human using them can predict the method's behaviour. You can then check if it is a number (matches("[1-9]+[0-9]*")) or just be wild and do Integer.parseInt() directly.

Seeing
    game = new GuessCalc(guess);
is a loop looks strange in class 1. That looks like an error since rounds will be reset constantly.

Edit 1:

If your code is not suppose to reset the random number every single round and reset the 'tries' count every round (the code threw away the current game every round) the below code may help you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.print("I will choose a number between 1 and 10" + '\n'
            + "You have 3 tries to get it right" + '\n');

        GuessCalc game = new GuessCalc();
        while (game.getRounds() <= 10) {

            game.playRound();
            System.out.println(game.wins());

        }

}
}
```

Second class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessCalc {
    private int wins, rounds = 0, num = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
    private int tries = 0;
    private Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
    * Constructs the game
    * 
    * @param guess
    *            the player's guess
    */
    public GuessCalc() {

    }

    /**
    * Runs the rounds and determines if they win
    * 
    * @return outcome if they won (true) or lost (false);
    */
    public boolean playRound() {
        startNewRound();
        System.out.printf("Round %d \n\n", this.getRounds());

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter a new guess: ");

            int guess = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

            printHotOrCold(guess);

            if (guess == num) {
                wins++;

                System.out.println("Jackpot! Setting a new random number");

                return true;
            }else if(tries==3){
                System.out.println("Oops, didn't succeed. Better luck next time. The number was "+num);

                return false;//ran out of tries
            }else{
                //got it wrong but still has guesses left
            }
        }

    }

    public final void startNewRound() {
         rounds++;
         tries = 0;
         num = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);// set a new random number    

    }

    /**
    * Tells the player if they are hot or cold
    */
    public void printHotOrCold(int guess) {

        int offBy = guess - num;

        if (offBy == 1 || offBy == -1) {// if they are over or under by 1
            System.out.println("Hot");
        } else if (guess != num) {// if they are further than 1 away
             System.out.println("Cold");
        }

        tries++;

    }

    /**
    * Returns the number of wins and makes a new header
    * 
    * @return the String with the number of wins and new header
    */
    public String wins() {
        String record = String.format("You have won %d out of %d rounds. \n\n",wins,rounds);
        return record;
    }

    /**
    * Returns the number of rounds played
    * 
    * @return rounds the number of rounds
    */
    public int getRounds() {
        return rounds;
    }

}
```

Your code was malformed (couldn't compile) and I don't 100% know your intent (ex unknown if it is 10 rounds to get as many random numbers correct as possible or they have 3 guesses in 10 rounds). Good luck.

Comment: Is it ok to get input from my second class? I could just make another method in there to handle new rounds but I was trying to keep all input in my client class(1)

Comment: @LazerWing You can, just not both like your code currently does. And in the second class, you are using nextInt which is what is causing your new error. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The idea is 3 tries per round, 10 rounds, and each round has a new number

Comment: What is the purpose of the boolean return on the makeGuess method I dont see it being used

Comment: @LazerWing If it is three tries per random number, you want the class to loop in the round. "What is the purpose of the boolean return on the makeGuess method I dont see it being used" same purpose as the String that was being returned before.

Answer (score 0):

try adding
`sc.nextLine();` after  `sc.nextInt();` which will consume the new line character